# Larva of Halyomorpha halys?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I just found these small insects on a Saponaria.

After search, it could be *Halyomorpha halys*, but I am really not sure.

[image]

[image: Potential larva of *Halyomorpha halys*]

Can anyone confirm? If so, should I kill them as they are considered as agricultural pest?

They are about 3-5mm. I am living in the south of Paris (48.814766, 2.334659)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [instar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instar) (nymph) of a shield or stink  bug (order [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera), family [Pentatomidae])(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae).

This appears to be similar to the 2nd (or possibly 3rd) instar of *Halyomorpha halys*.

[image]

European and Mediterranean Plant Protection Organization; Credit: Matteo Maspero

[UTIA](https://ag.tennessee.edu/EPP/Pages/Invasive%20Species/Insects/Brown-Marmorated-Stink-Bug.aspx) suggests the 2nd instar begins to develop an almost black appearance, where that blackness gradually shifts to browner shades in subsequent instars. According to [Medal *et al.* (2013)](https://bioone.org/journals/florida-entomologist/volume-96/issue-3/024.096.0370/Biology-of-the-Brown-Marmorated-Stink-Bug-iHalyomorpha-iihalys-i/10.1653/024.096.0370.full)<sup>1</sup> the 2nd and 3rd instars have median lengths of ~2.75 and ~4.25 mm, respectively. According to [WSU Extension](https://extension.wsu.edu/wam/brown-marmorated-stink-bug-halyomorpha-halys-a-guide-to-identification/), instar nymphs of *H. halys* are spiny (including on the shoulders) and possess light bands on the antennae.

[image]

<sup>Source: [WSU Extension](https://extension.wsu.edu/wam/brown-marmorated-stink-bug-halyomorpha-halys-a-guide-to-identification/)</sup>

This [University of Wisconsin Extension site](https://fyi.extension.wisc.edu/wihortupdate/files/2016/07/2016-07-Hort-Update-BMSB.pdf) provides a fairly similar photo to your specimens, which can be found at [bugguide.com](https://bugguide.net/node/view/437473):

[image]

<sup>Source: [bugguide.com](https://bugguide.net/node/view/437473); Credit: Yurika Alexander</sup>

---

<sup>Citations</sup>

1  <sup>Medal, J., Smith, T. and Santa Cruz, A., 2013. Biology of the brown marmorated stink bug Halyomorpha halys (Heteroptera: Pentatomidae) in the laboratory. *Florida Entomologist*, 96(3): 1209-1213. [PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Trevor_Smith11/publication/269580971_Biology_of_the_Brown_Marmorated_Stink_Bug_Halyomorpha_halys_Heteroptera_Pentatomidae_in_the_Laboratory/links/55d1fa0a08ae7fb244f40bd5/Biology-of-the-Brown-Marmorated-Stink-Bug-Halyomorpha-halys-Heteroptera-Pentatomidae-in-the-Laboratory.pdf)</sup>